# Laravel. Миграции. Добавление поля

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Вставляю поле так: `$table->timestamp('added_on')->default('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')`, но в SQLite значение по-умолчанию равно 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' и оно не работает(не заменяет на текущую дату).
Нужно чтобы поле имело значение CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,- тогда будет работать.
Можно ли это сделать в Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с Laravel 5.1 доступен следующий синтаксис:

```
$table->timestamp('added_on')->useCurrent();
```

Для Laravel < 5.1 необходимо использовать:

```
$table->timestamp('added_on')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!